LRstats() being used instead of summarise() and R error is "Error in sum(n, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument"
I have sample R code I was provided for a work assignment and one code chunk contained summarise() but R did not like that recommended LRstats() saying "Warning: 'summarise' is deprecated.
Use 'LRstats' instead.
See help("Deprecated")Error in UseMethod("rowwise") :
no applicable method for 'rowwise' applied to an object of class "function".
When I run the code chunk with LRstats() I keep getting an error "Error in sum(n, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument." I do not understand what the error is and any feedback or advice is appreciated.enter image description here
I researched this error online and found nothing. I have tried rerunning the code and substituting LRstats() with summarise() but that throws the error "Warning: 'summarise' is deprecated.
Use 'LRstats' instead.
See help("Deprecated")Error in sum(n, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument". I was expecting the code to run but instead the code error is "Error in sum(n, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument" when using LRstats()

Welcome to SO. We do not share code as image here. Please, edit your question with your code inside triple backticks and, if possible, share a sample of your data or provide some toy data, so others can try to reproduce your problem. This way you'll get better and faster help. Again: welcome and good luck.
